# How to concat observables with only one observer next emitted

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

Hello I want to achieve something with rxjs with a couple of constraints but I can't achieve them all at the same time.

What I want to achieve might be noted as so:

```
first$      ---x|
second$         ------x|
subscribe   -----------x|
```

But this is what I am getting:

```
first$      ---x|
second$         ------x|
subscribe   ---x------x
```

With this code:

```js
const checkFirstSide$: Observable<boolean> = this.checkSide('first');
const checkOtherSide$: Observable<boolean> = this.checkSide('other');

concat(
    checkFirstSide$,
    checkOtherSide$
).pipe(
    timeout(15000)
).subscribe({
    next: (success) => {
        doSomething(success);
    },
    error: (error) => {
        handleError(error);
    },
    complete: () => {
        doSomethingOnComplete();
    }
});
```

Constraints:

1. They should subscribe one after the other
2. They should only subscribe if previous one is successful (does not emit error)
3. Everything should timeout in 15 seconds
4. On any error it should abort (execute handleError and complete)
5. The observer `next` function should only be executed once and then `complete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either...

switch to the second observable when the first emits.

```ts
checkFirstSide$.pipe(
  switchMap(x => checkOtherSide$),
  timeout(15000)
)
```

or collect the values from your observables and emit them at the end.

```ts
concat(
  checkFirstSide$,
  checkOtherSide$
).pipe(
  toArray(),
  timeout(15000)
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually found the solution before you posted this one but you are the closes to an accepted answer.The solution I got is the use of `concat` and a `reduce((acc, value) => acc && value)` inside the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the behaviour you want is achieved through the forkJoin function. Check out the [official API reference](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin)!

---

EDIT: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your idea! I think I understando now...what you need is to use a pipe and the [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) operator:

```js
checkFirstSide$.pipe(
  switchMap(resFirstSide => {
    doSomething(resFirstSide);
    return checkOtherSide$;
  });
).subscribe(resOtherSide => doSomethingOnComplete());
```

Comment: But this is subscribing to all observables at once. I need them to be subscribed one after the other completes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you'll get would be [concat](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat) from the official API reference. But i am not sure how that behaves when one observable throws.

Comment: Concat is what I used in the example. Using it does emit as many `next` of the observer as observables are in it.